# I cannot Uninstall Tcl from my linux system

Tags: linux, centos, tcl, tk-toolkit

I installed tcl to learn it, however, I installed all the files in the wrong location. I am trying to uninstall it, But the uninstall file does not work. I am trying to carry out the instructions form their website:

```
To uninstall ActiveTcl, run the "uninstall.tcl" script that is located in the directory where you extracted the ActiveTcl archive. Note that you must use the "wish" in the distribution you wish to uninstall. For example:

% /path/Tcl/bin/wish /path/Tcl/lib/ppm/log/ActiveTcl/uninstall_ActiveTcl.tcl
stored, by default, in the directory /lib/ppm/log/ActiveTcl. You must use the wish interpreter from the distribution you wish to uninstall. Ensure that you do not run the uninstall script from a directory that will be removed during the uninstallation.

For example:

% /path/Tcl/bin/wish /path/Tcl/lib/ppm/log/ActiveTcl/uninstall_ActiveTcl.tcl
Note: if you are uninstalling both ActiveTcl and Tcl Dev Kit, uninstall Tcl Dev Kit before uninstalling ActiveTcl.
```

There is no uninstall_ActiveTcl.tcl. I do see an "uninstall" file but it does not have an extension, and I do not know how to run it.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the file to a uninstall.tcl file and see if that works. Take a back-up first though. Because we might need that file later

Comment: Yes, but how do I run it? I cannot even get wish to work. I tried changing it to .sh so i can bash it, still nothing

Comment: try running it with TCL itself, if it doesn't come up anymore, it probably isn't installed anymore

Comment: ok so i tried /path/to/wish /path/to/uninstall.tcl and it says application-specific initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: that is weird, if that didn't work, i dunno what will

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed it in a new location, compared the files that were installed between the old and the new location and deleted the file sin the old location. Unfortunately I could not delete many of the hidden files, as I did not know if they were there originally or if they belonged to Tcl. I am really surprised and disappointed there is no easy way to uninstall tcl properly.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you should uninstall ActiveTcl as follows:

1. Open a command prompt
2. Change directory to where you found the `install` file - e.g.

   $ cd path_to_Tcl_installation/bin
3. Run the file

   $ ./uninstall

On linux systems, you don't need any particular file extension in order to be able to run a file.

I don't know CentOS but a little googling led me to a forum [thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12844) that describes how to open a command prompt.

Good luck